# React-Native: Route is undefined and not an object when passing params from one screen to another

Tags: react-native

In my react-native app, I am trying to pass a parameter from one screen to another, in two separate files.
In my app.js I have the following code:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Button, View, Text } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

import TestScreen from "./screens/TestScreen";

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Test"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate("Test");
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Test"
          component={TestScreen}
          extraData={{ measurementId: 2 }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here I pass the `extraData` with my component TestSCreen on Stack.Screen.
In my TestScreen I have the following code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button, View, Text } from "react-native";

class TestScreen extends React.Component {
  render({ extraData, navigation }) {
    const { measurementId } = extraData.initialParams;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text>Test Screen</Text>
        <Text>measurementId: {measurementId}</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Home"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default TestScreen;
```

Where I pass the `extraData.measurementId` param to my `measurementId` constant.
But I keep receiving the error:

```js
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '\_ref.route')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass parameters to your screens you can use the `initialParams` property on the `Stack.Screen` component.

```js
<Stack.Screen
  name="Test"
  component={TestScreen}
  initialParams={{ measurementId: 2 }}
/>
```

And in your TestScreen you can use it like this.

```js
function TestScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  const { itemId } = route.params;

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Text>Test Screen</Text>
      <Text>measurementId: {measurementId}</Text>
      <Button title="Go to Home" onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Also, its not recommended to mix and match **class** and **functional** components.